# Finding the group element of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I have

```
$tallyArray =  Array
(
    ["Group1"] => Array
        (
            ["Item1"] => 2
            ["Item2"] => 1
        )
    ["Group2"] => Array
        (
            ["Item1"] => 1
            ["Item2"] => 1
        )
)
```

and I want to know if "Group1" already exist. Which is tested with variable `$grp = "Group1"` How do you do that.

Ive tried:

```
       $tas = sizeof($tallyArray);
        $grpPOS = 0;
        $grpFound = 'not found';
        for($z=0; $z <= $tas; $z++){
            if($tallyArray[$z] == $grp){
                $grpFound="found";
                $grpPOS = $z;
            }
        }
```

Ive tried

```
$grpFound = in_array_recursive($grp, $tallyArray) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Ive Tried

```
$grpFound = in_array($grp, $tallyArray) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

But non of these return "found".

Please help.

Comment: `if (isSet($tallArray[$grp]))` ? `in_array()` checks for value, not key

Comment: @kingkero - thanks, and sorry to be a idiot, but can you please elaborate.

Comment: How is this different from your other question that I've answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064254/add-to-multidimensional-array-with-key-value-pair

Comment: @mornenel This would probably be too much for the SO format. I suggest you learn what arrays are in PHP and how they work (via book, tutorial, video, ..)

Comment: @VladimirRamik - was not exactly what I was looking for, but contained useful information. Sorry

Comment: @kingkero - Thanks, I will, but I am trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `array_key_exists` which checks if the given key or index exists in the array.

```
if ( array_key_exists($grp, $tallyArray) ) {
    // do something
}
```